# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular-testing-app/node_modules/jwa'

Tags: jwt, angular6

I will install jsonwebtoken module in my angular6 project `npm i jsonwebtoken`. The jsonwebtoken module Dependencies jwa installed, But that index.js file crypto require error **Can't resolve 'crypto'**, But i already install crypto module. 
Please help and clear the issue.
My error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/jwa/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular-testing-app/node_modules/jwa'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular-testing-app/node_modules/jws/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular-testing-app/node_modules/jws/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular-testing-app/node_modules/jws/lib'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I faced the issue same as you and I resolved.
You can follow these steps:

1. Add this file to root directory

**patch.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const f = 'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js';

fs.readFile(f, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(/node: false/g, 'node: {crypto: true, stream: true}');

  fs.writeFile(f, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

2. Add this command to *package.json* file

**package.json**

```
{...
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node patch.js",
    ...
  }
}
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/niespodd/1fa82da6f8c901d1c33d2fcbb762947d

Answer (score 5):

But instead of using a pre-install, I just hand edited `node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js' and changed the lines in that regex:

```
// old:
node: false,
// new:
node: { crypto: true, stream: true },
```

Comment: this saved my day, very hacky but works for now.

Comment: this works for me. thanks. by the way My problem was in Vue.js 3.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify browser.js with this script, should fix it.....

```
 const fs = require('fs');
const f = 'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js';

fs.readFile(f, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  //necesario para que jsforce y algunas bibliotecas que aun usan el global de nodejs
  let result = data.replace(/node: false/g,
    `node:
    {
     crypto: true,
     stream: true,
     fs: 'empty',
     global: true,
     tls: 'empty',
     net: 'empty',
     process: true,
     module: false,
     clearImmediate: false,
     setImmediate: false

     }`);


  fs.writeFile(f, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
  });

});
```