# node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected error after installation of Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, build, installation, rxjs

I got an error of

> node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.

after the installation of Angular 6.

Check the error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

Comment: Hello @TheParam , I am getting error after the installation. I havn't done any code in it yet.

Comment: In Angular 6 required version of rxjs is 6.0.0 so please check below answer. it will help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54529119/9741113
this solved my problem, but now I can't import nothing from

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52530289 solved my problem with a postinstall patch that passes in crypto and stream

Comment: This is because your Angular version & also typescript version doesn't align with rxjs version. Please check whether those versions are compatible with each other.

Answer (score 455, accepted):

This problem might arise due to version mismatch. To solve your problem you need to do following changes in your **package.json** file.

**Step 1** : Go to `package.json` and modify `"rxjs": "^6.0.0"` to `"rxjs": "6.0.0"`

**Step 2** Run `npm install` in your project.

There is no need to change the typescript version. (Mine: `"typescript": "~2.7.2"`)

**Edit:** If you are using `rxjs-compat` then you also need to do following in order to fixed the issue. change the `rxjs-compat` version from `"rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2"` to `"rxjs-compat": "6.2.2"`

Hope this will help!

Comment: @SSP You should read how npm specify package versions. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Comment: ^ operator use  to get latest version of the library if available

Comment: Should we add an issue for angular 6?

Comment: acutally someone already did that here is link https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4511

Comment: Worked for angular 4 project !

Comment: If the above didn't work for you, add: "rxjs-compat": "6.2.2", to your package.json. Source and explanation:  https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4512

Comment: Thanks. had this: ```"rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",```
Changed to  ```"rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.2",```
Everything worked great.

Comment: This worked for me on an ionic project running v4.12.0 of the ionic cli

Comment: It solved the problem. Can anyone please elaborate why "rxjs": "^6.0.0" is not working?

Comment: This resolved an issue with an old angular app we use running ng 6.1.9

Answer (score 12):

You need to do some changes in `package.json`

Go to `package.json` and modify `"rxjs": "^6.0.0"` to `"rxjs": "6.0.0"`

Then run `npm update` in your project

Comment: First, I updated node using the .msi (i'm on windows 10) to the latest version. Then I changed the package.json as modified here and used npm update. I had to reboot my machine and after several tries, everything worked. Attempting to clear the npm cache did not work, and it made my computer hang.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error
using angular 6 having rxjs@6.4.0 but i downgraded it to rxjs@6.3.3
it worked.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I did clear rxjs and rxjs-compat from node_modules and downgraded the version then did npm install. Just to be sure that i am on right version.

Answer (score 7):

Go to the project directory run this command

npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save

Answer (score 5):

If you are using rxjs-compat then you also need to do following in order to fixed the issue. change the rxjs-compat version from

```
"rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2"
```

to

```
"rxjs-compat": "6.2.2"
```

This works for me

Answer (score 4):

I just needed to edit the file and add the semicolon at the final line after 0 as shown here:

Go to the path `[project directory]/node_modules/rxjs/internal` and open the file `types.d.ts` as administrator, move to the final of the file and add a semicolon.

**Original code:** `export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T : never;`

**Modified code:** `export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O; extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T : never;`

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem like a permanent solution. Next time you reinstall you project, the errors will probably be back!

Comment: @Zaphoid I agree with you, however, that was the easiest solution to this problem. I have no idea how such a widely used library has this problem. Your solution worked even in rxjs@6.6.3. I've seen some cases where a type library is needed, but people smarter than me did not mention this, so I'm assuming it does not exist for this rxjs module.

Answer (score 3):

Earlier, I used to fix the problem with @TheParam's answer but lately started using yarn. Sadly I could not find yarn equivalent of

```
nmp update
```

I tried using

```
yarn upgrade
```

(although it is not equivalent of above command afaik) and it did not help.

I instead used

```
yarn add rxjs@6.0.0
```

and it worked. It took considerable time 82 sec as compared to few seconds in case of npm but fixed the issue. my node 8.11.2 and yarn 1.15.2

Comment: Thank you.it takes 683 s for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

```
npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save

ng server
```

Comment: ng server should be ng serve

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem

```
npm install typescript@2.8.0
```

solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Go to package.json and update "rxjs": "^6.0.0" to "rxjs": "6.0.0"
after that do npm update

Answer (score 0):

if you are still facing the problem,
go to package.json

1. remove rxjs and add rxjs-compat
   also,
   "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0"
     to
   "rxjs-compat": "6.4.0",
2. change the typscript version to 2.8
3. run npm install

This will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the  "rxjs": "^6.0.0" to "rxjs": "6.0.0" didn't work. I had to update my angular CLI to last stable `npm install -g @angular/cli` and regenerate the project again.

My config now is :

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.6
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.9
```

Comment: Go to package.json and modify "rxjs": "^6.2.1" to "rxjs": "6.2.1"

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by version of typescript installed was not compatible with that of the rxjs installed.Installation of typescript as mentioned below helped me install the compatible version of typescript with that of the angular packages already installed.You can resolve the issue by the below command

```
npm install typescript
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine with me when I changed "rxjs" in package.json from "^6.0.0" to "6.0.0"
and then run

> "npm i"

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.reason might be due to version mismatch

`npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save` fix the error

Answer (score 0):

Just do the one changes in **package.json** file

```
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
```

Just delete the **^** like i did in the below code & update the npm(node package manager)

```
"rxjs": "6.0.0",
```

`npm update`

`ng serve --open`

Now file your project will start normally

Answer (score -1):

Go To **package.json** and modify **"rxjs": "^6.0.0"** to **"rxjs": "6.0.0"**

Then run

```
npm update
```

Then start the server

```
ng serve
```

Problem solved 100%