# Getting “error TS1005, TS1109” for Angular 6 project after start

Tags: typescript, build, installation, rxjs, angular6

I'm facing this problem to start the Angular 6 app. Does anyone have solution to this?

```
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

Tried a lot to solve this. Tried to install different versions of Node/RxJS as well. Yet no luck.

[Error - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaM3q.png)

[Tech Stack - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii1Fe.png)

Comment: Most likely related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529027/node-modules-rxjs-internal-types-d-ts81-44-error-ts1005-expected-error-a

Comment: Just check what RxJS version you have installed

Comment: Hello martin, I've already tried this out. Yet no luck. :/ Any other solution?

Comment: Not really. It looks like exactly what's described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529027/node-modules-rxjs-internal-types-d-ts81-44-error-ts1005-expected-error-a so I don't have any better idea

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, installing this solved the error

`npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i changed the next dependency

```
"rxjs": "^6.0.0" ===>  "rxjs": "6.0.0"
```

I only removed the ^ symbol and removed node_modules folder and run "npm i" like last step and it's worked for me. I hope it works you you.