# Why does Angular 6 fail to compile with this message: ?wdm?: Failed to compile

Tags: angular

I have just installed Angular **6.0.8**

I use typescript **2.7.1**

I created a new angular app but it fails to compile. I don't know what's the problem as you see the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running npm install and then serve your app. Works for me.

Comment: I did but it did not work. The error is not clear for me. I googled it but still didn't find solution.

Comment: Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529027/node-modules-rxjs-internal-types-d-ts81-44-error-ts1005-expected-error-a) might be compatibilty issue

Comment: It's helpful discussion and I solved it by getting package.json file from the course author and it worked. @MAil