# ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(90,44): error TS1005: ';' expected

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs

I'm building my Angular Application.But, when I execute the application using ng serve -o or by pressing run in IntellijI got the following error.

```
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(90,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(90,74): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(90,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(91,52): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(91,88): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(91,92): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

I have inspected types.d.ts as I know it is created by Angular. I'm not able to understand the error. Note that after I got this error I deleted node_modules and I installed using npm install wished I got away still I got this error. I tried a lot of solutions proposing by old posts (2019)

Here is my package.JSON file:

```
{
  "name": "search-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.7.3",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  }
}
```

my versions :

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 14.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.10
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.10
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.10
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.6.7
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Any help is more than appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have to use an old angular version ? Can't you use latest ? Are you in strict mode in tsconfig.json ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node\_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected error after installation of Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529027/node-modules-rxjs-internal-types-d-ts81-44-error-ts1005-expected-error-a)

Comment: @RameshRajendran yes I tested it and I got this error                                          

npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@6.1.10
node_modules/@angular/core
@angular/core@"^6.0.0" from the root project
peer @angular/core@"6.1.10" from @angular/animations@6.1.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
    @angular/animations@"^6.1.10" from the root project
   8 more (@angular/common, @angular/forms, @angular/http, ...)
 peer @angular/core@"^2.0.0||^4.0.0" from angular2-jwt@0.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/angular2-jwt
npm ERR!   angular2-jwt@"0.2.3" from the root project

Comment: @BertrandPETIT i'm using 6.0.8 versionno im not in strict mode